# Python - compare list elements and return the value

Tags: python-3.x

How do i check the elements in a list 
Example:

```
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

I want to compare `l[0]` & `l[1]` to all the elements and return me 1 and 2 if they match with any other elements in the list.

Comment: Do you want to return `l[0]`and `l[1]` if and only if both are found in the list, or do you want to return `l[0]` if `l[0]` is found but `l[1]` is not and `l[1]` if `l[1]` is found but `l[0]` is not?

Comment: I want to return l[0] if l[0] is found but l[1] is not and l[1] if l[1] is found but l[0] is not. If l[0] and l[1] are both found return both of them.

Comment: in other words, just compare and return whatever is found

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**This can work:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
if numbers.count(numbers[0])-1: print(numbers[0])
if numbers.count(numbers[1])-1: print(numbers[1])
>>>1
>>>2
```

or if you just want to compare and return whatever is found, you can use collections.Counter()

```
from collections import Counter
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
number = Counter(numbers)
print(number)
print(str(numbers[0]) + ':' + str(number[numbers[0]]))# item and number of 
print(str(numbers[1]) + ':' + str(number[numbers[1]]))# occurancies
>>>Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1})
>>>1:2
>>>2:2
```

Comment: I am not sure the answer has a proper formatting (I am using a very old pc with a very old browser now. All the pages look weird here). Sorry if I broke post rules

Answer (score 0):

```
if l.count(l[0]) > 1 and l.count(l[1]) > 1:
    print l[0], l[1]
elif l.count(l[0]):
    print l[0]
elif l.count(l[1]):
    print l[1]
```

or with list comprehension

```
[i for i in l[:2] if l.count(i) > 1]
```